# "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json" using Youtube's JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I'm receiving a "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json" error message using Google Chrome's JavaScript console.

I'm currently running the following code on my local computer:

```
var URL = "";
var YOUTUBE_ROOT = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=jsonc&v=2";
var start_index = "&start-index=1";
var callback = "&jsonp=?"
function searchYouTube()
{
  var q = encodeURIComponent(jQuery("#query").val());
  var query = "&q="+q;
  URL = YOUTUBE_ROOT+start_index+query+callback; 
  alert(URL);
    $.getJSON(URL, function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            alert(item);
        });
    });


}


jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery("#searchYouTube").click(searchYouTube);

});
```

May I know what is causing the error?

I've tried using 'callback=?' , 'jsoncallback=?' for the callback, but all leads to the
same error message.

May I know how do i fix this?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you use JSONP, you should code it like this IMHO :

```
$.ajax(URL, {
    crossDomain:true, 
    dataType: "jsonp", 
    success:function(data,text,xhqr){
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            alert(item);
        });
    }
});
```

The correct parameter is `callback` but jQuery generates one automagically so dont specify it.

Comment: wow thanks! seems like i still have a lot to learn with regards to JavaScript and JQuery. the data is showing up now.

Comment: JSONP is used when you need to access cross domain data. Basically it's just a trick : a javascript scriptag is inserted in your page and the response have a javascript callback embedded.

Comment: This does not solve the error mentioned ('Resource interpreted'... etc.), at least not for me, and when still serving with `application/json`. It only goes away when serving as `text/javascript`, which doesn't have any noticeable side effects.

Comment: It does not alert anything on my side

Answer (score 4):

That's a warning, not an error, and shouldn't stop your code from working.

The fault is with YouTube for serving the data with the wrong content-type.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirk in Chrome and how it differentiates an a XHR request from a typical browser request.

To prevent the message appearing and also allow chrome to render the response nicely as json in the console, append a query string to your request URL.

e.g

```
var xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = 'mysite.com/party_in_my_pants'; // Using this one, Chrome throws error

var url = 'mysite.com/party_in_my_pants?'; // This one, Chrome is sexy.

xhr_object.open('POST', url, false);
```